# Making one row with colspan first row of the Wordpress options page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html-table, meta-boxes

In my WordPress options page, for creating fields I am using [Fluent Framework](https://github.com/HeadwayLabs/fluent). It is similar to [Meta Box](https://metabox.io/). So both of them use `do_settings_fields` function and the function generates the code like this:

```
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 1</th>
    <td>Element 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 2</th>
    <td>Element 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 3</th>
    <td>Element 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">Header 4</th>
    <td>Element 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

In this table, I want to use firs row as a one row like this:

[image]

I creted a javascript file to fields/custom_html directory and hide scope with jQuery and enqueue the javascript file like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('th[scope="row"]').first().hide();
});
```

But this doesn't completely solve my problem. Because I don't mind if I only use one row, but it's very problematic for multi-rows. Maybe I need to close the `table` tag and open a new `table` tag again, but I haven't been able to do this with my limited jQuery knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging two columns you have to use "colspan" attributes which can helpful, Here I am sharing the code for jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $table_head = jQuery('tr').first();
  var value = $table_head.text();
  $table_head.html('<th colspan="2">'+value+'</th>');
});
```